# Is there a way to use R to find repeated words on a website? For example a news article

Tags: r

Say I am using the url (https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/09/success/eviction-moratorium-landlord-plans/index.html) and want to know find what words are repeated most often, what is the best way to go about this using R? The end goal I'm trying to get to is that I will run the command and it will say word = "blank", quantity = x

Comment: The first thing I'd do is write a function to fetch the contents of the URL (maybe with the httr package) and store it in an appropriate R data structure. Have you gotten that far yet?

Comment: I tried: read.csv(url("https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/09/success/eviction-moratorium-landlord-plans/index.html")) and then I used ngram to try to find how many times words are repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fetch the url contents, combine the contents as a character vector of length 1, split by space, and return a frequency distribution of words sorted in descending order.

```
library(magrittr)
library(textreadr)
read_html("https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/09/success/eviction-moratorium-landlord-plans/index.html") %>%
    paste0(collapse=' ') %>%
    strsplit(split=' ') %>%
    table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    arrange(desc(Freq))


                             . Freq
1                           the   63
2                            to   54
3                            of   42
4                           and   40
5                           for   28
```

Comment: What a great answer @Bill O'Brien. Didn't know about that library.